# ListView's offset state is lost during PushNamed GoRouter

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView` of cards. Clicking on a card takes you to a detailed page. I push the screen using `context.pushNamed` via `GoRouter`. Upon clicking on back `<`, I am always taken to the beginning of the list.

I want to preserve the scrolling offset when back to the list view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the scrolling offset of a ListView when navigating back to the list view page, you can utilize the ScrollController class. Here's how you can achieve this:

Create a ScrollController instance to control the scrolling behavior of your ListView.
Attach this ScrollController to your ListView.
Store the scrolling offset of the ListView in a variable when navigating away from the list view page.
Restore the scrolling offset when navigating back to the list view page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListViewPageState createState() => _ListViewPageState();
}

class _ListViewPageState extends State<ListViewPage> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double _scrollOffset = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    _scrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('List View')),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Detail Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the offset of the ListView (using a ScrollController to handle that value), or you can use the id of the detailed item itself, when going back use the result parameter and pass the previous offset or id of the item and use the ScrollController from the ListView to scroll to that position (either directly the offset or the position of the item in the list).

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, when navigating between screens, widgets are often rebuilt by default. However, with [the flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package, you can control this behavior using the buildWhen property.

Here's an example demonstrating how to prevent unnecessary rebuilding of a ListView screen:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

// Define a simple BLoC to manage the state of the ListView screen
class MyBloc extends Cubit<int> {
  MyBloc() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => MyBloc(),
        child: ListViewScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ListView Screen'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<MyBloc, int>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: state,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        // Set buildWhen to false to prevent unnecessary rebuilding
        buildWhen: (previousState, state) => false,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context).increment();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).